# Finding how many records are open in a month, in a dataset containing single records with start and end dates in r

Tags: r, date, count

I have a data frame where each row is a record with its id, start and end dates. I would like to create another data frame that contains every calendar month's start dates (eg "2020-01-01" is January), and a second column counting how many unique records are open (for any/all portion of) that month.

I could create new columns for each calendar month and generate dummies for whether a record is open that month, then add up each column. What's a more efficient way of doing this?

```
ds <- data.frame(record_id = c("00a", "00b", "00c"),
                 record_start_date = as.Date(c("2020-01-16", "2020-03-25", "2020-02-22")),
                 record_end_date = as.Date(c("2020-12-05", "2020-06-21", "2020-11-12")))
```

Comment: Look at the `tidyr::complete` function

Comment: Can you spell out more specifically what "how many records are open that month" means? Unique records (can an id count more than once in a month)? As of the start/end of the month, or open at any point in the month?

Comment: Thanks I edited my question to make it clearer. In this case I'm looking for a unique count of all records that may be open for some/all of a given month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/) package was created for working with intervals like this. `iv_count_between()` is perfect for this problem.

```r
library(ivs)
library(dplyr)
library(clock)

ds <- data.frame(
  record_id = c("00a", "00b", "00c"),
  record_start_date = as.Date(c("2020-01-16", "2020-03-25", "2020-02-22")),
  record_end_date = as.Date(c("2020-12-05", "2020-06-21", "2020-11-12"))
)

# Record the start and end months to generate the counts for
start <- date_start(min(ds$record_start_date), "year")
end <- date_end(max(ds$record_end_date), "year") + 1L

# Construct an interval vector
ds <- ds %>%
  mutate(
    record_range = iv(record_start_date, record_end_date), 
    .keep = "unused"
  )

ds
#>   record_id             record_range
#> 1       00a [2020-01-16, 2020-12-05)
#> 2       00b [2020-03-25, 2020-06-21)
#> 3       00c [2020-02-22, 2020-11-12)

# Generate the months sequence to count along
result <- tibble(
  month = date_seq(
    from = start, 
    to = end, 
    by = duration_months(1)
  )
)

# Count the number of times `month[[i]]` is between any of the
# ranges in `ds$record_range`
result %>%
  mutate(
    count = iv_count_between(month, ds$record_range)
  )
#> # A tibble: 13 × 2
#>    month      count
#>    <date>     <int>
#>  1 2020-01-01     0
#>  2 2020-02-01     1
#>  3 2020-03-01     2
#>  4 2020-04-01     3
#>  5 2020-05-01     3
#>  6 2020-06-01     3
#>  7 2020-07-01     2
#>  8 2020-08-01     2
#>  9 2020-09-01     2
#> 10 2020-10-01     2
#> 11 2020-11-01     2
#> 12 2020-12-01     1
#> 13 2021-01-01     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach where we reshape the data and add rows for each month start. Then it can be a very efficient vectorized cumulative count to figure out the active records as of the end of the 1st of each month. If you want to count a record that ends on the 1st (or one that ends the same day it began) toward the count, you could add a line to shift end dates one day later.

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)
ds %>%
  pivot_longer(-record_id) %>%
  mutate(change = if_else(name == "record_start_date", 1, -1)) %>%
  # mutate(value = value + if_else(name == "record_end_date", 1, 0)) %>%
  add_row(name = "month_start", 
          value = seq.Date(floor_date(min(ds$record_start_date), "month"),
                           floor_date(max(ds$record_end_date), "month"),
                           by = "month"),
          change = 0) %>%
  arrange(value, desc(name)) %>%
  mutate(count = cumsum(change)) %>%
  filter(name == "month_start") %>% 
  select(value, count)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   value      count
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01     0
 2 2020-02-01     1
 3 2020-03-01     2
 4 2020-04-01     3
 5 2020-05-01     3
 6 2020-06-01     3
 7 2020-07-01     2
 8 2020-08-01     2
 9 2020-09-01     2
10 2020-10-01     2
11 2020-11-01     2
12 2020-12-01     1
```